# How to remove REGEXEXTRACT #N/A error and ignore special characters in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have column A:A containing titles. In another column I want to show the first letter of title, ignoring special characters, like so:

| Title | Chapter |
| --- | --- |
| (A) Title | A |
| Title | T |

This is an array formula put on B1 I made so far, but not working properly as my example above:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(A:A)=1,"Chapter",REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,".")))
```

It contains an error message `#N/A` on every row if column A doesn't have text. It also shows a special character if it begins with. This is how it currently looks:

| Title | Chapter |
| --- | --- |
| (A) Title | ( |
| Title | T |
|  | #N/A |
|  | #N/A |

Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try the simpler

```
=ArrayFormula({"Title "; 
        IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"\w"),)})
```

(do adjust ranges to your needs)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Compared to the other answer where I have some issues sorting my columns, I don't have any sorting-problems using this formula instead!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps

```
={"Chapter"; ArrayFormula(left(regexreplace(A2:A, "[^A-Za-z]*",), 1))}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thnx that's working so far! Is there a way to exclude numbers out of the special characters?

Comment: Nvm I found it out myself using `"[^A-Za-z0-9]*"` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple `If isBlank?`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2), "", REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\w"))
```

translates to

```
if Title Cell is blank
   empty string 
else 
   extract regex
```

This is more readable than the ArrayFormula solution

[image]